# Use cell value to define how many columns to select

Tags: excel, vba

I'm totally new to VBA although I'm pretty seasoned with Excel formulas. I'm working in a clinical administration role which I will be leaving early next year and I want to leave things in a state where less IT-literate colleagues can continue to use some of the stuff I've made.

The main issue we're facing is that when we extract data from the clinical software, it by default only spits out patient ID, name, address, DOB etc. If we ask the software to put in any additional details, such as date of diagnosis with various diseases, it puts this data in new columns to the LEFT of the patient, which obviously makes it impossible to do a vlookup. The current macro I use basically selects the first 3 or 4 columns of exported data, and then cut/pastes them to the right-most part of the spreadsheet and then copies the patient IDs into a separate table where the vlookup does its thing and populates the table.

What I'm looking for is a way of creating something of a template, where a use can specify how many of these "extra" columns there are going to be, probably using a drop-down list, so the macro can be easily adjusted for new data sets. I've had a search around but I haven't managed to find anything quite suitable.

Here's the bit of code which currently selects the data and moves it:

```
Sheets("Exported Data").Select
Columns("A:E").Select
Selection.Cut
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
Columns("N:N").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A2").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exported Data").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exported Data").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A2:A1285"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exported Data").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:M1285")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use INDEX and MATCH instead of VLOOKUP. INDEX and MATCH let you pull back values to the left of the lookup column.

```
 ColA   ColB    Ref ColD    ColE        
 12     111     aaa 3000    4001            
 13     122     bbb 3001    4002            
 14     133     ccc 3002    4003            


 =INDEX(A2:B4,MATCH(G1,C2:C4,0),2)
```

The formula looks up the "bbb" in Ref column and pulls back the "122" from ColB.

You use MATCH to determine the row and INDEX to determine the column to pull back.

That might save you the trouble of all that cutting and pasting.

Comment: Thanks for this, this has definitely simplified things! Still need to figure out how I'm going to set up a template that will automatically create columns with this formula in though. My role is split between IT and Admin work so it might be a little while before I get a chance to properly tinker with it, but thank you.